# Completely reset Outlook 2007 to first run

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

I have a problem with Outlook 2007. I did something wrong at first and now it doesn't start.

I entered some Exchange server setting by mistake and it keeps saying that there is no Exchange server network.

I reinstalled Office but the problem didn't go away and I continue to get the same error. I've also tried the following command but that didn't work either:

```
outlook /firstrun
```

How can I reset Outlook to its first run settings? I want to clear those Exchange server settings that I entered initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Outlook open?  If so Click Tools, Account Settings and select the account created and click Remove

If it does not, open control Panel and then Mail (Classic View In XP) and click Show Profiles.  Remove the profile you created.

Comment: no outlook doen not open. because of this lame problem. I am on windows 7, how do I do that?